# Is a twisted pair conductor intrinsically succeptible to thermal noise?

Tags: noise, thermal

I am working with a noise sensitive application where the thermal noise is much larger than was anticipated.

There is a resistive sensor (wheatstone bridge) that is subject to various constant temperature conditions served by a constant current feed and twist pair, shielded  sense.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWB1H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Typically the twist pair is done to minimize noise and EM. Would there be any other obvious unforseen contribution to observed thermal noise from the TP?

The reason that I believe the noise is Johnson-nNquist and not general broadband noise is because the mean amplitude scales as a square of the temperature pretty well. Although other sources are certainly not out of the question

Comment: What do you mean by "thermal noise"? Thermal noise is normally considered Johnson-Nyquist noise which is a function of resistance and temperature only. If it's something else, a schematic would be useful.

Comment: What @SpehroPefhany said, unless the twisted pair line is long enough to be lossy.  Johnson-Nyquist noise is constant with temperature (-174dBm/Hz into a matched load at 300 kelvin, -168dBm/Hz referenced to your source impedance if it's a 100% mismatched load, such as a high-impedance amplifier).

Comment: Are you sure it's thermal noise you're seeing, and not broadband noise in your follow-on electronics?

Comment: Your last assumption is incorrect. But you may need a CM shield to the twist pair or an RF cap to AC earth gnd to 0Vdc. A LPF equiv cct. with added shunt capacitance will reduce noise. Constant current source is susceptible unlike a CV to stray noise.  Show setup.

Comment: Thanks folks, I am working on getting a reasonable reference setup :)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Noise mean amplitude scales as the square of the temp, so yes, I mean Johnson-Nyquist. My understanding is that KT noise does appear across a capacitance, which is also Johnson-Nyquist to my understanding, but that may be incorrect.

Comment: Capacitance has no thermal noise, BTW, at least ideally. Of course there are other forms of noise such as triboelectric, and if the wires are very high Z and have a high voltage across them then changes in capacitance from thermal effects on the dielectric could add noise. Mostly not a consideration in a typical low resistance bridge setup.. schematic please, with values? If your actual thermal noise is higher than anticipated either you have more resistance then anticipated or higher temperature, neither of which seems likely.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am working on getting schematics, but the operating temperature is a titch high :) just unexpected noise given previous testing.

Comment: Reference Material Provided

Comment: @TimWescott certainly not out of the question that it is another source of noise but it scales correctly with temperature, I have updated the question

Comment: @SpehroPefhany my previous understanding is that switched capacitor circuits will have Johnson-nyquist noise when the charge is transfered after switching, Would that that mean that when n analyzing noise in that application thathe ESR and other parasitic resistances are the primary variables? This is probably a better second question

Comment: Yes, just lossy things cause thermal noise (with analogs in the mechanical world too). But unless you're operating at cryogenic temperatures (which is possible) "a lot higher" noise implies a lot higher sqrt(absolute temperature) and that's a lot. To get double room temperature (~300K) noise you'd need 1200K or over 900°C.

Comment: Crasic, does it matter what type of noise it is? You could use a spectrum analyzer to identify it (or its components). Also, your application could filter the noisy measurement (analog/digital), but I'm guessing you've thought of that, and you are focusing on the noise source here.

Comment: So your differential resistance is 5K and the Johnson-Nyquist noise from the bridge (assuming the leadwire resistances are << 5K) and T = 120°C should be ~0.33uV RMS over a 1kHz bandwidth, which is pretty difficult to measure. I'm guessing there might be some other effect at work here.

Comment: Your signal BW is very low <1Hz compared to thermal noise, so what’s the problem with a Cap filtering it out? Is it CM noise or Dif Mode noise

Comment: Are you sure your Current source is valid for this app?

Comment: _"the thermal noise is much larger than was anticipated"_ - How much noise were you anticipating, and how much did you get? _"the mean amplitude scales as a square of the temperature pretty well."_ - Exactly which sensor are you using? What makes you think the cable is the source of the noise?

Comment: @BruceAbbot the part was tested previously independently, and while I would suspect other radiators, the temperature dependence of the mean amplitude (scales as root temp) is confirmed and was surprising as it had not been previously observed, to your point we expected very little thermal noise with the cable being the biggest visible change  .  Could metal enclosures surrounding such a sensor  radiate as sources?

Comment: Still no numbers. How do expect us to have an answer when we don't even know the magnitude of the problem?

Comment: Maybe 1/f noise. By the way, Johnson-Nyquist (white) noise is a special case of the more general  Fluctuation–Dissipation theorem. Which is a special case of Mother Nature being what she is oft accused of being.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111319/discussion-on-question-by-crasic-is-a-twisted-pair-conductor-intrinsically-succe).

Answer (score 0):

The noise density of 62 ohms is 1 nanoVolt/rootHertz.

The noise density of 62/1,00,000 ohms is 1 picoVolt/rootHertz.
That is about the noise of an inch of wire.

Of course the bandwidth is very high.

You will need to add low_pass_filters downstream.

Comment: When I do spectral analysis, most of the noise energy is <10Hz and scales can in mean amplitude  as root temperature

Comment: @crasic "Most of the noise is < 10Hz". That is a VERY significant "detail" omitted from the question. Please add it and mention LF noise in the title. It changes a lot; omitting it almost counts as mis-direction.